# How to get an Integer from a specific line of a text file in Python?

Tags: python

I need some help with a task in python.
The task is to make a program that downloads a text file from the internet.
Then you have to find "Saturday" and "Sunday" in the text file.
Next to those are the temperatures.
The task is to calculate the average temperature of the weekend.
*I am not allowed to change the text file.*

Here is an example of the text file contents:

```
Thursday: 21
Friday: 19
Saturday: 13
Sunday: 17
Monday: 19
Tuesday: 21
Wednesday: 16
```

well... i found which line they are but i don't know how to get the temperatures. I need to seperate the numbers from the text and assign them to my two variables temp1 and temp2.
I would be grateful if you could help me.
(sorry for my english. i am not a native speaker.)

```
import urllib.request

my_list = list()
word1 = "Saturday"
word2 = "Sunday"
temp1 = 0
temp2 = 0
average = (temp1 + temp2) / 2

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.senarclens.eu/~gerald/teaching/cms/data/fc.txt", "fc.txt")



open('fc.txt', 'r')
with open('fc.txt')  as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if word1 in line:
        print("Word \"{}\" found in line {}".format(word1, i + 1))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if word2 in line:
        print("Word \"{}\" found in line {}".format(word2, i + 1))
# need the temperature next to the name of day for temp1, temp2




if average > 25:
    print("Next weekend, swimming would be a good activity.")
elif average >= 12 and average < 25:
    print("Next weekend, hiking would be a good activity.")
elif average >= 5 and average < 12:
    print("Next weekend, watching movies would be a good activity.")
elif average >= -5 and average < 5:
    print("Next weekend, relaxing in the local hot springs would be a good activity.")
else:
    print("Next weekend, skiing would be a good activity.")
```

Comment: Add the filename of the temperatures or at least a part of it

Comment: You can use, for example, `int("Saturday: 13".split()[-1])` to get 13 as an int. So, use something like: `temp1 = int(line.split()[-1])` and similarly for temp2.

Comment: Function `split()` is what you need to split a string into a list. It's an EXTREMELY important function and almost every language has an implementation of it (although the name may be slightly different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text file is always going to be in this format, you can use a split function and not worry about regex ever.

You won't need two for loops

```
daily_temps = {}

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    splits = line.split(":")
    day = splits[0].strip()
    temp = int(splits[-1].strip())
    daily_temps[day] = temp
```

The `strip` removes any extra spaces

This will give you

```py
{'Thursday': 25, 'Friday': 19, 'Saturday': 13 ...}
```

Then you do

```py
temp1 = daily_temps['Saturday']

temp2 = daily_temps['Sunday']

average = (temp1 + temp2) / 2

if average > 25:
    print("Next weekend, swimming would be a good activity.")
```

The `average` declaration you have before you set `temp1` and `temp2` is wrong. Declare it after they've been set.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. I got an error before. I just changed this: 
            
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    splits = line.split(":")
    day = splits[0].strip()
    temp = splits[-1].strip()
    daily_temps[day] = temp

temp1 = int(daily_temps['Saturday'])

temp2 = int(daily_temps['Sunday'])

Comment: i moved the "int" to temp1 temp2. now the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to get integers, so basically you don't need to enumerate lines by yourself. This code will help you get what you need:

```py
import re
data = """Friday: 10
Sunday: 12,
...
Sunday: 33,
"""
>>> re.findall(r'Sunday:\s\d{1,3}', data, re.MULTILINE)
['Sunday: 12', 'Sunday: 33']
```

Comment: Your regex finds only sunday. But it appears he wants Saturday and sunday

Comment: you're right, it's not complete solution, I only provided a way to do that. This is only building block which is needed. And, that answers "How to get an Integer" from text.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common scraping scenario, something that is nice to train on, using requests, beautifulsoup, scrapy, selenium, etc, good luck with your endeavor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests,re
url = "https://www.senarclens.eu/~gerald/teaching/cms/data/fc.txt"
r = requests.get(url)
dat = r.text
out = {}
for l in dat.split('\n'):
    m = re.search(r'(\w+)\:\s+(\d+)', l)
    if m and m.group(2):
        out[m.group(1)] = int(m.group(2))
print(out)
```

giving:

```
{'Thursday': 21, 'Friday': 19, 'Saturday': 13, \
'Sunday': 17, 'Monday': 19, 'Tuesday': 21, 'Wednesday': 16}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use .split() method to split word1 and word2 to separate the number from the text, then you can take the average by using only the number part by indexing it, and then turning it into an int:

```
temp1 = word1.split(":")
temp2 = word2.split(":")
average = (int(temp1[1]) + int(temp2[1])) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split(': ')` for each `line` in text file. When checking `word` in `line`, assign `temp` from index 1 of splitted line for `word1` and `word2`. Lastly, do the calculation.

```
import urllib.request

word1 = "Saturday"
word2 = "Sunday"

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.senarclens.eu/~gerald/teaching/cms/data/fc.txt", "fc.txt")

with open('fc.txt')  as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if word1 in line:
            temp1 = line.split(': ')[1]
            print(f"Word '{word1}' found in line {i} with temperature {temp1}")
        if word2 in line:
            temp2 = line.split(': ')[1]
            print(f"Word '{word2}' found in line {i} with temperature {temp2}")
    average = (int(temp1) + int(temp2)) // 2

    print(f'{word1} : {temp1}')
    print(f'{word2} : {temp2}')
    print(f'Average temperature : {average}')

if average > 25:
    print("Next weekend, swimming would be a good activity.")
elif average >= 12 and average < 25:
    print("Next weekend, hiking would be a good activity.")
elif average >= 5 and average < 12:
    print("Next weekend, watching movies would be a good activity.")
elif average >= -5 and average < 5:
    print("Next weekend, relaxing in the local hot springs would be a good activity.")
else:
    print("Next weekend, skiing would be a good activity.")
```

Output:

```
Word 'Saturday' found in line 2 with temperature 13
Word 'Sunday' found in line 3 with temperature 17
Saturday : 13
Sunday : 17
Average temperature : 15
Next weekend, hiking would be a good activity.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try splitting each line with the ':' character, and get the second part of the returned list.

Like you split the lines on the txt file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).